# Stop my image resizing with max-width: 100%

Tags: html, css, skeleton-css-boilerplate

I'm using a three-column Skeleton layout for my website. All works how I want it apart from one thing. I have an image aligned and above a table. See below:

http://www.cosworth-europe.co.uk/catalogue/pistonringsets.html

If I add `max-width:100%;` to the image it slightly shrinks and moves it out of line with my table before I've even resized by browser. See here:

http://www.cosworth-europe.co.uk/catalogue/pistonringsets2.html

Is there a way I can keep the `max-width`, but so it doesn't resize at all until the screen size changes?

HTML

```
<div class="six columns">
    <img src="../images/catalogue/pistonringslarge.jpg">
    <p style="padding-top:10px;"></p>

    <table style="font-size:11px; width:380px; margin-left:20px;">
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td style="padding-right:5px; width:70px;">Product Code</td>
                <td style="background-color:#133D8D; color:white; padding-left:5px;">Description</td>
            </tr>
```

CSS

```
.container .six.columns {
    width: 340px;
}
```

Comment: Your `.six.columns` div is 340px wide, so the img is too (its natural width is 399px). Everything behaves exactly as expected. Except that the table below is wider, but the table overflows out of the div. You can check for yourself if you apply `overflow-x:hidden` to the div, then you'll see that the img is the exact same width as the visible part of the table.

Comment: Thanks Mr Lister, I see your point now. The table is overflowing and is the issue - do you have any suggestions, should I put a max-width on my table?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

as Mr Listed pointed out... my image was fine, it was in fact the table that had overgrown the div due to adding a 20px margin. I removed the margin and added max-width:100% to my table. all works great now.